# rake db:migrate doesn't work (Rails 4.0.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rails-migrations

I have a new app on Rails 4.0.4 / Ruby 2.1.0. The first thing I did was adding Devise gem. When I want to run rake db:migrate, it just does nothing. No error, but the migration isn't executed.

Could you please help me what to do with this case? I can't find where is the problem.

Thank You!
Petr

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so the problem was that Devise generator generated ".txt" file with migration instead of ".rb" file. Strange, but changing extension solved it.

Comment: Could you share the versions of your `rails` and `devise`.  That's strange you got `.txt` with the Devise `generator`.

Comment: Rails is 4.0.3 and Devise is 3.2.4.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as you Petr and I think I found out why.  For some reason when I ran 'rails g devise User', it created a migration (db/migrate/[timestamp]_devise_create_users.rb).  That's what it suppose to be, but upon further examination, the migration was missing the '.rb' at the end.  So it looked like (db/migrate/[timestamp]_devise_create_users). When I added the .rb at the end, and ran 'rake db:migrate' it worked like a charm.  I don't know why rails didn't attach the '.rb' at the end.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After you install devise gem, you have to do the following

1. `rails generate devise:install`

The generator will install an initializer which describes ALL Devise's configuration options and you MUST take a look at it. When you are done, you are ready to add Devise to any of your models using the generator

1. `rails generate devise <model>`

This is the step that generates the migration. For eg, If you want to add devise to user model, you should do

```
rails generate devise User
```

So it will generate a migration to add devise related columns to users table

Comment: Of course I did this. But after doing this, command "rake db:migrate" doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see the new migration?

Comment: Yes, I see new migration file. But after "rake db:migrate" nothing happens, schema file is still empty and rails raises error "Could not find table 'users'" as it doesn't exist. The problem is in rake command, but I don't know how to solve it.