# After devise install, could not find table 'users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm following the One Month Rails course and installed devise into my rails app, but after running a db migration, it kept coming up with this error below:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::SessionsController#new
Could not find table 'users'
```

I checked with one of the teachers and he saw that my migration file didn't have an .rb extension. He said they've seen it a few times with some devise versions.

Added the .rb extension, and it worked like a charm. I didn't see this answered elsewhere, so I'm posting it here. Hopefully, this will help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered before: [rake db:migrate doesn't work (Rails 4.0.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582772/rake-dbmigrate-doesnt-work-rails-4-0-4)

According to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2971 it was fixed in Devise 3.2.3.